# RecyclerView разрешить фокус только по одному элементу

Tags: android, recyclerview

Нужно сделать так, чтобы в RecyclerView нельзя было кликать одновременно по нескольким элементам.

Такое ограничение стоит автоматически в ListView. Что отвечает за это ограничение?

Гифка (почему-то не вставляется): https://i.stack.imgur.com/dI5YC.jpg

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте прописать в разметке у вашего RecyclerView следующий атрибут:

```
android:splitMotionEvents="false"
```

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup#attr_android:splitMotionEvents